# Overload a JS plugin function with a function from inside

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, jquery-plugins, overloading

I want to call a function which is in my plugin.

I overloaded a function but I want to call another function from it.

```
$("mySelector").Myplugin({
    My_function : function (){
        *do some stuf*
        function_from_the_plugin();
    }
});
```

An error appears that says "Unknown function". I think it do not search the function in the plugin but outside.
Do you know how I can do?

I already try with "this", a variable corresponding to my plugin object.

If you have an idea please share it with me.

Thank you for reading this post.

Comment: So you're passing to the plugin, as init parameter, a hacked function? Not sure what you're trying to achieve here, can you give more details?

Comment: Yes I want to make possible for the user to mofified the secondary function in the plugin but i want that he can call the primary function inside the secondary function.
Here it's my function "reset" after the treatment of the data.

Comment: This very much depends on how the plugin is structured. How does `function_from_the_plugin` look?

Comment: But here you're just calling the plugin, it's just its initialization. So you're just passing parameters to it, like a config object. That's not where you call the functions and stuff, it's just telling it which way to initialize. It could be : `Myplugin({
    setting1 : true, setting2 : false });` Once the plugin is initialized, you can call its methods.

Comment: Yeah but the idea is to configure the plugin correctly and it will work alone correctly. It's the plugin which call the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this.function_from_the_plugin(); in code where Myplugin() is initialized.

Comment: i am saying add this.function_from_the_plugin(); in plugin init function not in calling that function because first that plugin should initialize in order to access the other functions of that plugin

Comment: I do not understand yout point sorry, can you be more precised please. Thanx for you answer ^^